# Entity Framework 5.0 - Delete object without retrieving it

Tags: entity-framework-5

I want to delete a database entry like this:

```
public bool DeletePersonById(int id)
    {
        var p = new Person() { ID = id };
        //ctx.Person.Attach(p);
        ctx.Entry<Person>(p).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        return true;
    }
```

then I get an InvalidOperationException with the following message:

> The key field 'FirstName' cannot have a value of null. A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'Person'.

So, for me it doesn't matter if a property can or cannot be null in this case, because I only want to delete the complete row/object.
Object was loaded with `AsNoTracking()`

```
(from p in ctx.Person.AsNoTracking() where p.ID == id select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my table didn't have a primary key, after adding a pk on this db table and regenerating the ef model, the above code works.